# Expanding Einstein Notation in Geodesic Equation

Tags: differential-geometry

I have all my Christoffel symbols generated and I'm ready to start trying to solve the coupled differential equations for a geodesic in three dimensions, but I don't know how many equations I need.  Given the formula with the Einstein notation:$$\frac{d^2u^k}{d\lambda ^2}+\Gamma^k_{ij}\frac{du^i}{d\lambda}\frac{du^j}{d\lambda}=0$$
How do I figure out how many individual equations there are to solve if I have a spherical surface ($r,\theta,\phi$)?  My first pass was to do something like:
$$\frac{d^2r}{d\lambda ^2}+\Gamma^r_{rr}\frac{dr}{d\lambda}\frac{dr}{d\lambda}=0$$
$$\frac{d^2r}{d\lambda ^2}+\Gamma^r_{r\theta}\frac{dr}{d\lambda}\frac{d\theta}{d\lambda}=0$$
$$...$$
$$\frac{d^2\phi}{d\lambda ^2}+\Gamma^\phi_{\phi\phi}\frac{d\phi}{d\lambda}\frac{d\phi}{d\lambda}=0$$
And so on for 27 (3x3x3) equations, but that doesn't seem right.  My next thought was that the expressions probably summed independently, so I tried:
$$\frac{d^2r}{d\lambda ^2}+\Gamma^r_{rr}\frac{dr}{d\lambda}\frac{dr}{d\lambda}+\Gamma^r_{r\theta}\frac{dr}{d\lambda}\frac{d\theta}{d\lambda}...\Gamma^r_{\phi\phi}\frac{d\phi}{d\lambda}\frac{d\phi}{d\lambda}=0$$
Which would work out to 3 equations.  While I can't find a specific rule for how the two terms in the original equation are summed, it seems logical that the $k$ iterator would link the first and second term.  In English, it seems like I want to iterate over the first term with $r,\theta,\phi$ for three equations, and in each of those three equations, iterate over every combination of ($i={r,\theta,\phi},j={r,\theta,\phi}$)

Comment: You are summing over the $i$'s and $j$'s and so the number of equations are the number of choices for $k$. Hence there are 3 equations. Switching to spherical coordinates doesn't change that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're working in $3$ dimensions, $k \in \{1,2,3\}$, so you have $3$ equations total (one for each value of $k$). Explicitly, you have:
\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
\ddot{u}^1 +  \sum \limits_{i,j = 1}^3\Gamma^1_{ij} \dot{u}^i \dot{u}^j &= 0 \\\\
\ddot{u}^2 +  \sum \limits_{i,j = 1}^3\Gamma^2_{ij} \dot{u}^i \dot{u}^j &= 0 \\\\
\ddot{u}^3 +  \sum \limits_{i,j = 1}^3\Gamma^3_{ij} \dot{u}^i \dot{u}^j &= 0
\end{cases}
\end{align}
(where I use $\dot{}$ to mean $\frac{d}{d \lambda}$ for convenience)

Now, in polar coordinates, it might be more convenient to use the actual letters $r,\theta, \phi$ rather than numbers $1,2,3$. So, let's agree to label $1 \leftrightarrow r, 2 \leftrightarrow \theta$ and $3 \leftrightarrow \phi$. Then, the first equation written out in complete glory says:
\begin{align}
0 &= \ddot{r}  \\
&+\Gamma^r_{rr} \dot{r} \dot{r} + \Gamma^{r}_{r \theta} \dot{r}\dot{\theta} + \Gamma^{r}_{r \phi} \dot{r}\dot{\phi} \\
&+ \Gamma^r_{\theta r} \dot{\theta} \dot{r} + \Gamma^{r}_{\theta \theta} \dot{\theta}\dot{\theta} + \Gamma^{r}_{\theta \phi} \dot{\theta}\dot{\phi} \\
&+ \Gamma^r_{\phi r} \dot{\phi} \dot{r} + \Gamma^{r}_{\phi \theta} \dot{\phi}\dot{\theta} + \Gamma^{r}_{\phi \phi} \dot{\phi}\dot{\phi} 
\end{align}

The second equation in complete gory detail is:
\begin{align}
0 &= \ddot{\theta}  \\
&+\Gamma^{\theta}_{rr} \dot{r} \dot{r} + \Gamma^{\theta}_{r \theta} \dot{r}\dot{\theta} + \Gamma^{\theta}_{r \phi} \dot{r}\dot{\phi} \\
&+ \Gamma^{\theta}_{\theta r} \dot{\theta} \dot{r} + \Gamma^{\theta}_{\theta \theta} \dot{\theta}\dot{\theta} + \Gamma^{\theta}_{\theta \phi} \dot{\theta}\dot{\phi} \\
&+ \Gamma^{\theta}_{\phi r} \dot{\phi} \dot{r} + \Gamma^{\theta}_{\phi \theta} \dot{\phi}\dot{\theta} + \Gamma^{\theta}_{\phi \phi} \dot{\phi}\dot{\phi} 
\end{align}

The third equation in complete detail is:
\begin{align}
0 &= \ddot{\phi}  \\
&+\Gamma^{\phi}_{rr} \dot{r} \dot{r} + \Gamma^{\phi}_{r \theta} \dot{r}\dot{\theta} + \Gamma^{\phi}_{r \phi} \dot{r}\dot{\phi} \\
&+ \Gamma^{\phi}_{\theta r} \dot{\theta} \dot{r} + \Gamma^{\phi}_{\theta \theta} \dot{\theta}\dot{\theta} + \Gamma^{\phi}_{\theta \phi} \dot{\theta}\dot{\phi} \\
&+ \Gamma^{\phi}_{\phi r} \dot{\phi} \dot{r} + \Gamma^{\phi}_{\phi \theta} \dot{\phi}\dot{\theta} + \Gamma^{\phi}_{\phi \phi} \dot{\phi}\dot{\phi} 
\end{align}

Given these explicit equations, you now have to figure out what the $\Gamma^k_{ij}$'s are for your prescribed connection in terms of spherical coordinates, and then plug them in (so at the end, the $\Gamma$'s will be functions of $(r,\theta, \phi)$).

---

These three long equations is summarized by the statement: for all $k \in \{1,2,3\}$,
\begin{align}
\ddot{u}^k + \sum_{i=1}^3 \sum_{j=1}^3 \Gamma^{k}_{ij} \dot{u}^i \dot{u}^j &= 0
\end{align}
Or if we adopt the Einstein convention we ignore writing $\sum$ signs whenever there are up-down indices which are the same:
\begin{align}
\ddot{u}^k +  \Gamma^{k}_{ij} \dot{u}^i \dot{u}^j &= 0 \tag{$*$}
\end{align}

---

By the way, note that $(*)$ is the same as any of the following equations: for all $k \in \{1,2,3\}$,
\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
\ddot{u}^k +  \Gamma^{k}_{\alpha \beta} \dot{u}^{\alpha} \dot{u}^{\beta} &= 0 \\\\
\ddot{u}^k +  \Gamma^{k}_{ab} \dot{u}^{a} \dot{u}^{b} &= 0 \\\\
\ddot{u}^k +  \Gamma^{k}_{\mu \nu} \dot{u}^{\mu} \dot{u}^{\nu} &= 0 \\\\
\ddot{u}^k +  \Gamma^{k}_{@ \ddot{\smile}} \dot{u}^{@} \dot{u}^{\ddot{\smile}} &= 0
\end{cases}
\end{align}
In other words, the actual symbol you use for the summation index doesn't matter at all!

Comment: that was a lot of typing, so I definitely might have made a mistake. If you think there is one, let me know.

Comment: Thank you.  I've read several descriptions and seen some videos, but I wasn't able to find this description anywhere.  It makes a big difference being able to see the iterators expanded explicitly like that.

Comment: BTW, I wrote this out by hand last night using the $\frac{du^i}{d\lambda}$ notation.  I understand now why the dot convention was invented.